# Check if a number is not in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

Please I need ur help
I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    var seats_available = <?php echo json_encode($seats_available); ?>;
                    var schedule_id = <?php echo json_encode($schedule_id); ?>;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "check_if_avaliable.php",
                        method: 'POST',
                        data:{
                            seats_available:seats_available,
                            schedule_id:schedule_id
                        },
                        success: function(data1){
                            $('#msg').html(data1);
                            if(data1.indexOf(1) === -1){
                                document.getElementById("s1").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat1']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }

                            if(data1.indexOf(2)=== -1){
                                document.getElementById("s2").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat2']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(3)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s3").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat3']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(4)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s4").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat4']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(5)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s5").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat5']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.lastIndexOf(6)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s6").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat6']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(7)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s7").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat7']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(8)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s8").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat8']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(9)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s9").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat9']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(10)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s10").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat10']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(11)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s11").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat11']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(12)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s12").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat12']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(13)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s13").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat13']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(14)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s14").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat14']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(15)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s15").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat15']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            if(data1.indexOf(16)===-1){
                                document.getElementById("s16").style.backgroundColor= "red";
                                $("input[name='seat16']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I want to know when a seat number is not in the array, but it like indexOf() reads both the key and values at the same time. please how do i solve this problem

the data1 is an array of this type:Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [15] => 16 ) , I have 16 Seats, and I want to know when the seat is nolonger avaliable. the seat is not avaliable when it is nolonger in the array of data1. Am using indexOf() to do that, but is not working out

Comment: Description of your problem doesn't make sense. You should give clearly understandable description.

Comment: Your data is not an array.

Comment: do you know about underscore.js, It is best js for javascript collection. you simply can apply functions of that js...

Comment: i think your problem can solve by difference function of that js. please refer link http://underscorejs.org/#difference

Comment: data1 is the values that was returned from check_if_avaliable.php, I want to Know when a seat is not in data1, which is a json values. ie: {"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6,"6":7,"7":8,"8":9,"9":10,"10":11,"11":12,"12":13,"13":14,"15":16}, am using index of to check it, but is like indexOf() reads both the key and value of the JSON string, please what do i do, i need it to read only the Values

Comment: How do we know if a seat is available from your JSON data? This: `{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,...}` has no meaning to me. Is `0` the seat nr. and one means `true`? ... you must explain better in your question. What data do you have and what does that data mean, what do you expect in which case...

Comment: the data1 is an array of this type:Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [15] => 16 ) , I have 16 Seats, and I want to know when the seat is nolonger avaliable. the seat is not avaliable when it is nolonger in the array of data1.    Am using indexOf()  to do that, but is not working out

Answer (score -1):

your data is type of json object not array so you should do

```
data1.indexOf["0"] to access value
```

so for value you could iterate in keys and compare value:

```
for(key in data) {
   if(data[key] == toFindInt)
       console.log("found")
}
```